# Can I save a serialized Object in a File using FileChooser (javafx)?

Tags: java, file, serialization, javafx, save

The titel is pretty selfexplainatory. I want to save the serialized "spiel"
as a "name.ser" file using filechooser. I also want to load the file and return it to my controller. I have no idea how to connect the objectoutputstream and the filechooser.

```
public class Speicher {

    public void spielstandSpeichern(Spiel spiel, String name) { // Save File

    try{

        FileChooser fs = new FileChooser();

        fs.setInitialDirectory(new File("/Saves"));
        fs.setTitle("Spiel speichern");

        fs.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Ser", ".ser")
        );

        //File file =



        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Saves/save1.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(spiel);

        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public Spiel spielstandLaden() {  // Load File

    Spiel spiel = null;

    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Saves/save1.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        spiel = (Spiel) ois.readObject();

        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return spiel;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `showSaveDialog` respectively `showOpenDialog` on the FileChooser instance to get the file handle object for loading and saving. You can use this file handle object on your FileInputStream and FileOutputStream constructors.

Comment: Thank you it seems to be working. But i just realized I can not load the object "Spiel" as a whole because some classes in Spiel contain Images. Theses Images are not serialized. Do you have any idea how I could fix that ?

Comment: In Java, only objects implementing `java.io.Serializable` take cake of object serialization (most of the basic types such as String, Integer and so on do). Please make sure required fields are Serializable and do not have a `transient` modifier. To answer your question, you should provide snippet of your "Spiel" class definition.

Comment: my snippet is in the answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me out on this :) I m using the MVC architecture. So the following is my class "Spiel". Basically the mother of my model. Every other class in the model lives inside here. "Spiel" itself is being handeld by "Fassade" with "Speicher" (the class that saves/loads Spiel), the only model classes not inside of "Spiel".

"Spiel" and every class in the model beneath it implements Serializable. But in some classes I create new Image() when first initializing them. When loading a saved "Spiel" JavaFX cannot recreate the Images because they are not serialized.

Do you know how I could fix this so that I can save/ load games?

```
public class Spiel implements Serializable {

// Attribute
private static final long serialVersionUID = 16L;

private Spielzug spielzug;
private ArrayList<Spieler> spieler;

private Map map;

private Deck deck;
private Ablage ablage;
private OffeneKarten offeneKarten;

private ArrayList<RoutenBP> routenBP;
private ArrayList<StadtBP> stadtBP;
private AlleProvinzenBP alleProvinzenBP;

// Konstruktor
public Spiel(ArrayList<Spieler> spieler) {

    this.spieler = spieler;

    map = new Map();

    deck = new Deck();
    ablage = new Ablage(map);
    ablage.kartenVerteilen(deck.getDeck());
    offeneKarten = new OffeneKarten(deck);

    spielzug = new Spielzug(spieler.get(0));

    bpInitialisieren();
}

// Methoden

// Initialisierung
private void bpInitialisieren()
{
    //Routen BP initialisieren
            routenBP = new ArrayList<RoutenBP>();
            ArrayList<Image> routenImg = new ArrayList<Image>();

            routenImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_S5_2.png"));
            routenImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_S5_1.png"));
            RoutenBP routenbp_1 = new RoutenBP(5, 2, 2, "Du brauchst eine geschlossene Route der Laenge 5, um dieses Bonusplaettchen zu erhalten.", routenImg);
            routenBP.add(routenbp_1);

            routenImg.clear();
            routenImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_S6_3.png"));
            routenImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_S6_2.png"));
            routenImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_S6_1.png"));
            RoutenBP routenbp_2 = new RoutenBP(6, 3, 3, "Du brauchst eine geschlossene Route der Laenge 6, um dieses Bonusplaettchen zu erhalten.", routenImg);
            routenBP.add(routenbp_2);

            routenImg.clear();
            routenImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_S7_4.png"));
            routenImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_S7_3.png"));
            routenImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_S7_2.png"));
            routenImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_S7_1.png"));
            RoutenBP routenbp_3 = new RoutenBP(6, 4, 4, "Du brauchst eine geschlossene Route der Laenge 7, um dieses Bonusplaettchen zu erhalten.",routenImg);
            routenBP.add(routenbp_3);

            //Stadt BP initialisieren
            stadtBP = new ArrayList<StadtBP>();
            ArrayList<Image> stadtbpImg = new ArrayList<Image>();

            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_lilaP_3.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_lilaP_2.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_lilaP_1.png"));
            ArrayList<Karte> benoetigteStaedte = new ArrayList<Karte>();
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(3));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(4));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(10));
            StadtBP stadtbp_1 = new StadtBP(benoetigteStaedte, 3, 3, "Du brauchst in Freiburg, Mannheim und Carlsruhe ein Haus, um dieses Bonusplaettchen zu erhalten.",stadtbpImg);
            stadtBP.add(stadtbp_1);

            stadtbpImg.clear();
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_blauP_3.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_blauP_1.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_blauP_2.png"));
            benoetigteStaedte.clear();
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(1));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(21));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(6));
            StadtBP stadtbp_2 = new StadtBP(benoetigteStaedte, 3, 3, "Du brauchst in Basel, Zuerich und Innsbruck ein Haus, um dieses Bonusplaettchen zu erhalten.",stadtbpImg);
            stadtBP.add(stadtbp_2);

            stadtbpImg.clear();
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_gruenP_3.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_gruenP_2.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_gruenP_1.png"));
            benoetigteStaedte.clear();
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(17));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(18));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(19));
            StadtBP stadtbp_3 = new StadtBP(benoetigteStaedte, 3, 3, "Du brauchst in Sigmaringen, Stuttgart und Ulm ein Haus, um dieses Bonusplaettchen zu erhalten.",stadtbpImg);
            stadtBP.add(stadtbp_3);

            stadtbpImg.clear();
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_rotP_4.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_rotP_3.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_rotP_2.png"));
            benoetigteStaedte.clear();
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(2));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(8));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(14));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(16));
            StadtBP stadtbp_4 = new StadtBP(benoetigteStaedte, 4, 3, "Du brauchst in Budweis, Pilsen, Linz und Salzburg ein Haus, um dieses Bonusplaettchen zu erhalten.",stadtbpImg);
            stadtBP.add(stadtbp_4);

            stadtbpImg.clear();
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_beigeP_5.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_beigeP_4.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_beigeP_3.png"));
            stadtbpImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_beigeP_2.png"));
            benoetigteStaedte.clear();
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(0));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(5));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(7));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(11));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(12));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(13));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(15));
            benoetigteStaedte.add(map.getStadt(20));
            StadtBP stadtbp_5 = new StadtBP(benoetigteStaedte, 5, 4, "Du brauchst in Augsburg, Ingolstadt, Kempten, Münschen, Nürnberg, Passau, Regensburg und Würzburg ein Haus, um dieses Bonusplaettchen zu erhalten.",stadtbpImg);
            stadtBP.add(stadtbp_5);

            //Alle Provinzen BP initialisieren
            ArrayList<Image> alleProvImg = new ArrayList<Image>();
            alleProvImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_alleP_6.png"));
            alleProvImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_alleP_5.png"));
            alleProvImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_alleP_4.png"));
            alleProvImg.add(new Image("Bilder/bp_alleP_3.png"));
            alleProvinzenBP = new AlleProvinzenBP(map.getProvinzen(), 6,4, "Du brauchst in min. einer Stadt jeder Provinz ein Haus, um dieses Bonusplaettchen zu erhalten.",alleProvImg);
}

// Methoden

/**
 * Nimmt den jetzigen Spieler entgegegen und uebergibt den naechsten.
 *
 * @param spieler der jetzt fertig ist
 * @return spieler der jetzt dran ist
 */
public void naechsterSpieler() {

    int idx = spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getSpielerNr();

    if( idx == spieler.size() ) {
        idx = 0;
    }

    System.out.println("SPIEL: Anzahl spieler: "+spieler.size());
    spielzug.setAktuellerSpieler(spieler.get(idx));

    System.out.println("SPIEL: nächster Spieler ist "+spieler.get(idx).getName()+" mit SpielerNr "+ spieler.get(idx).getSpielerNr());
}

public void bpVergeben()
{
    for(RoutenBP rbp : routenBP)
    {
        if(rbp.bedingungErfuellt(spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getRoute().getStaedte(), spielzug))
        {
            // gibt BP an Spieler
            spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getRoutenBP().add(rbp);
            // gibt Punkte für BP an Spieler
            int p = spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getPunkte()
                        + rbp.getPunkte(spielzug.getPhase());
            spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().setPunkte(p);
        }
    }

    for(StadtBP sbp : stadtBP)
    {
        if(sbp.bedingungErfuellt(spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getRoute().getStaedte(), spielzug))
        {
            // gibt BP an Spieler
            spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getStadtBP().add(sbp);
            // gibt Punkte für BP an Spieler
            int p = spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getPunkte()
                        +sbp.getPunkte(spielzug.getPhase());
            spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().setPunkte(p);
        }
    }

    if(alleProvinzenBP.bedingungErfuellt(spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getRoute().getStaedte(), spielzug))
    {
        // gibt BP an Spieler
        spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().setAlleProvinzBP(alleProvinzenBP);
        // gibt Punkte für BP an Spieler
        int p = spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getPunkte()
                    +alleProvinzenBP.getPunkte(spielzug.getPhase());
        spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().setPunkte(p);
    }

}
public void kutscheAktualisieren() {

    if(spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getKutsche().bedingungErfuellt(spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getRoute().getStaedte(), spielzug))
    {
        int p = spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getPunkte()
                    + spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getKutsche().getPunkte(spielzug.getPhase());
        spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().setPunkte(p);
    }
}
public void hauspunkteVergeben()
{
    if(spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getHaeuser()
            .bedingungErfuellt(spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getRoute().getStaedte(), spielzug))
    {
        int p = spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getPunkte()
                    + spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().getHaeuser().getPunkte(spielzug.getPhase());
        spielzug.getAktuellerSpieler().setPunkte(p);
    }
}





// Setter und Getter FUnktionen


public Spielzug getSpielzug() {
    return spielzug;
}

public void setSpielzug(Spielzug spielzug) {
    this.spielzug = spielzug;
}

public ArrayList<Spieler> getSpieler() {
    return spieler;
}

public void setSpieler(ArrayList<Spieler> spieler) {
    this.spieler = spieler;
}

public Map getMap() {
    return map;
}

public void setMap(Map map) {
    this.map = map;
}

public Deck getDeck() {
    return deck;
}

public void setDeck(Deck deck) {
    this.deck = deck;
}

public Ablage getAblage() {
    return ablage;
}

public void setAblage(Ablage ablage) {
    this.ablage = ablage;
}

public OffeneKarten getOffeneKarten() {
    return offeneKarten;
}

public void setOffeneKarten(OffeneKarten offeneKarten) {
    this.offeneKarten = offeneKarten;
}

public ArrayList<RoutenBP> getRoutenBP() {
    return routenBP;
}

public ArrayList<StadtBP> getStadtBP() {
    return stadtBP;
}

public AlleProvinzenBP getAlleProvinzenBP() {
    return alleProvinzenBP;
}}
```

Comment: I think that classes take part of Serialization should have a non-arg constructor defined. What Image objects are you using. You question was based on javafx, so i assume it is `javafx.scene.image.Image` which is not implementing `Serializable`. If so, try to use a different class, from which you can create javafx Image objects. If you need the full power of serialization, you can implement:
`private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;` to enhance the normal process.

Comment: So I could implement a class "Picture" that extends Image and implements Serialziable? Thats very helpful, thanks

Comment: I did not test this, but i have my doubts. The whole class hierarchy needs to be Serializable. You can try using object composition an create a Picture class (implements Serializable) with a transient field of type Image and a String field capturing the image path. In your getImage method, you can create the Image object (if null) using the String path.